# innerHTML property null

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, innerhtml

The first file is 'faq-contents.html'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="faq-classification">
    </div>
  
<script src="faq-contents.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

linked "faq-contents.js" file.

```
const faqContents = [
    {order: "00",
        question: "Our mission",
    answer: "our mission answer"

    },
    {order:"01",
        question: "How does Linstock work?",
    answer: "it works well"
    },
]

const faqCenter = document.querySelector(".faq-classification")
const questionClicked = document.querySelectorAll("#faq-question")

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
});

questionClicked.forEach(function(click){
    click.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        const questionsAndAnswer = e.currentTarget.dataset.order;

        const restoredFaq = faqContents.filter(function(faqItem){

            if(faqItem.order === questionsAndAnswer) {
                                
                let result = 
                `<section id="faq-section">
                         <div class="faq-classification">
                    
                         </div>
                         <div class="faq-main-contents">
                             <h3 class="faq-question-title">
                             "${faqItem.question}"
                             </h3>
                             <p class="faq-answer-conntents">
                              "${faqItem.answer}"
                    
                             </p>
                         </div>
                     </section>`

                faqCenter.innerHTML = result

                return result;
            
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Here is another code file related to the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Frequently Asked Questions(FAQ)</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="faq" class="faq">
     
            <div class="faq-category">

                <div class="faq-contents">
                    <h2>About Linstock</h2>
                    <p id="faq-question" data-order="00"><a href="#faq-contents.html">Our mission</a></p>
                    <p id="faq-question" data-order="01"> How does Linstock work?</p>

               
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
    


    <script src="faq-contents.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to show objects of Q&A restored in `const faqContets` in case that the string "Our mission" in third file is clicked.

I tried to show the contents with `faqCenter.innerHTML = result` but innerHTML property is null.

How do I fix it?

Comment: An unrelated feedback: do not reuse `id` like in `faq-question`. This will only lead to issues. Related: you probably try to fetch `faqCenter` and the whole `faqCenter` is `null`. [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is a string property and should never be `null`.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Could  you clarify a bit what you want to happen when the user clicks Our Mission - what is a href="#faq-contents.html" to do?

Comment: @Lain Thanks. Then, how should I use ```id```? Can you give me examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your first problem, innerHTML property is null, look at the document the js can access:

faq-contents.js is loaded in both html files and adds the click eventlistener to every #faq-question.

- For faq-contents.html, it does have .faq-classifications, BUT no #faq-question => the forEach is executed 0 times, resulting in no eventlisteners added thus not doing anything.
- For index.html, it has #faq-question twice, so clicking fires it (duh).
  BUT: this page does not have .faq-classifications => faqCenter = null

Other mentions for your code:

- `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { });` <= don't close it directly, put some code inside of the {}, otherwise it is useless. Probably you put the `});` to high in the file by accident.
- skip the filter and return stuff and use forEach or something similar, as you are already getting the result out by `faqCenter.innerHTML = result`

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting `faqCenter` using a class name. You can have multiple element with the same class within the same page therefore 'faqCenter' is an array of objects.

As you only have one element in your array, you can simply do this:

```js
  faqCenter[0].innerHTML = result
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(.classname)`  returns the first element matching the selector. There is no array or `NodeList` involved.